# how to partition mst of iris dataset to obtain sub graphs in r

Tags: r

i'm new to r , can anyone give idea of how to obtain sub graphs for iris dataset mst tree?
  here i have done little code for obtaining mst tree for iris dataset.. i dono how to proceed further to obtain the sub trees of original mst tree..
here is my code..

```
library(cluster)
library(igraph)
data<-(iris)
g<-graph.data.frame(data,directed=FALSE)
plot(g,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold,edge.label=E(g)$weight)
mst<-minimum.spanning.tree(g)
plot(mst,layout=layout.reingold.tilford,edge.label=E(mst)$weight)
```

Comment: Please include a `library()` call for all non-base packages.

Comment: Also please make sure your code runs before you post it. You have a typo: `layout.fruchterman,reingold` should be `layout.fruchterman.reingold` and `layoout` should be `layout`.

Comment: Thankyou ,, now i included the library() packages and edited my code...